# PHP Codeigniter foreach collapse

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I want to make this kind of collapse in my php. Here is an example:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Heading</a>
<div id="collapse1">
  <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">
    Category
  </a>
</div>
<div id="collapse2">Items</div>
```

I want to apply something like that, in here:

```
<?php
$i=1;foreach($itemlist as $value) {
    echo "<h3>Tower Type : ".$value['notower']."</h3><br>";

    foreach($value['items'] as $val) { ?>
      <?= "<h4>".$val['groupem']."</h4><br>"; ?>
      <table class ="table table-bordered table-hovered table-striped table-condensed">
        <thead>
          <th><?= "Item Name" ?></th>
          <th><?= "Value" ?>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($val['item'] as $v) :?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $v['nm_detailem']?></td>
                <td><?= $v['em_value']?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    <?php } ?>

<?php } ?>
```

How can I do that? I'm stuck at where to put those `href`.

Comment: What do you plan on checking to create the breaks? Or do you want one every iteration of the loop?

Comment: i want on every iteration of the loops...i already tried to make some collapse,but when i closed one of the groups,all data become collapsed.@atoms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
$sOutput = '';
foreach ( $aData as $sData){

     If($sOutput != ''){
         $sOutput .= '</div><div class="collapse hidden">';
     }
     $sOutput .= '<a href=""></a>';
}

If(count($sOutput) == 1 && $sOutput !== ''){$sOutput .= '</div>';}
```

Add to css:

```
.hidden{display:none;}
```

Your jQuery could be:

```
$(".collapse").on('click', function(){
    $('.collapse').addClass('hidden');
    $(this).removeClass('hidden');
});
```